# Remove eldest entry from scala LinkedHashMap

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm trying to use scala's `LinkedHashMap` as an LRU cache, but I'm not sure how to remove the oldest entry of such a map. I know java's `LinkedHashMap` has a method `removeEldestEntry`, but there does not seem to be a similar method for scala's implementation. I'd prefer not to convert to java's implementation just to have access to `removeEldestEntry`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you want to remove the oldest entry in the HashMap or the LRU? because if you want to remove the LRU entry then you would have rearrange the HashMap each time you access an element

Comment: `removeEldestEntry` is not accessible in the sense you are implying. It is available for subclasses of `LinkedHashMap` to override and provide direction for aging out entries. Instead you can use `init` to get every element except the last.

Comment: Either oldest or LRU is fine.

Comment: Isn't `head` the "oldest" entry? So `tail` would give you a `LinkedHashMap` without the oldest entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
def removeOldestEntry[K](m: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, _]): m.type =
  m -= m.head._1
```

(Kudos to Jasper-M for pointing out that `head` will give the oldest entry)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the following way:

```
    object myApp {
      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val myMap = new MyLinkedHashMap[Int,String]() 
        myMap.add(1, "a")   // Map(1 -> a)
        myMap.add(2, "b")   // Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)
        myMap.add(3, "c")   // Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c)
        myMap.add(4, "d")   // Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> d)
        myMap.removeEldest  // Map(2 -> b, 3 -> c, 4 -> d)
        myMap.get(2)        // Map(3 -> c, 4 -> d, 2 -> b)
        myMap.removeEldest  // Map(4 -> d, 2 -> b)
  }
}

    class MyLinkedHashMap[K,V] {
      import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
      var map = new LinkedHashMap[K, V]()

      /* adds an element to the HaskMap */
      def add(key: K, value: V) {
        map.put(key, value)
      }

      /* removes the LRU element from the HaskMap */
      def removeEldest {
        if (!map.isEmpty) {
          map = map.drop(1)
        }
      }

      /* gets the value for the given key and moves it to the top of the HashMap */
      def get(key: K): Option[V] = {
        val value = map.remove(key)
        if (value != None) {
          map.put(key, value.get)
        }
        return value
      }
    }
```

Comment: Bit late but... newer ever use both: `var` and `collection.mutable.*`. Choose one... not both.